# Which characters need to be escaped in different contexts of JavaScript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

What are the characters that the standard requires to be escaped in context of character sets, capturing groups, etc?
For example, to match a slash character, `/` obviously needs to be escaped like `\/`.
However, when the slash is in a character set, both `[/]` and `[\/]` work on all browsers I've tested.

Which characters *are* and *aren't* required to be escaped by the standard in each context?